# Append <key, value> pair dynamically in API response if data not available in DB using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

We have a requirement to build an API response in JSON which will contain monthKey and participants count for last 12 months. If for a particular month, there is no entry available in DB, then dynamically create a <key, value> pair like <monthKey, 0> while building the JSON response in spring boot.

For ex: If we have only 2 months of data out of last 12 months, then the JSON would look like -

```
"participants": [
            {
            "monthKey": "202007",
            "totalParticipantsCount": 0
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        {
            "monthKey": "202105",
            "totalParticipantsCount": 0
        },
        {
            "monthKey": "202106",
            "totalParticipantsCount": 0
        }
        {
            "monthKey": "202107",
            "totalParticipantsCount": 25
        },
        {
            "monthKey": "202108",
            "totalParticipantsCount": 10
        }

    ]
```

Below is the code I've written in Spring Boot, but this code only builds the JSON response for the months which has data. I have created a dynamic MAP, but not able reach to the final stage where we can build the JSON response with all the 12 months data -

```
public ParticipantReportDto getParticipantsReport(
      List<ParticipantAggResult> participantAggResults,
      ReportTrendType trendType) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(participantAggResults)) {
      return ParticipantReportDto.builder()
                                              .participants(new ArrayList<>())
                                              .build();
    }

    Map<Integer, Long> monthParticipantMap = getMonthParticipantMap(
        participantAggResults);
    YearMonth thisMonth = YearMonth.now();

    // Inside this for loop we are adding the missing monthKey and adding ParticipantCount as 0
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
      if (!monthParticipantMap.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(thisMonth.minusMonths(i)
                                                                     .format(
                                                                         monthYearFormatter)))) {
        monthParticipantMap.put(Integer.parseInt(thisMonth.minusMonths(i)
                                                          .format(monthYearFormatter)), 0L);
      }
    }

    System.out.printf("PRINTING MONTH PARTICIPANT MAP %s\n", monthParticipantMap);
    // OUTPUT: {202103=0, 202102=0, 202101=0, 202107=25, 202011=0, 202106=0, 202010=0, 202105=0,
    // 202104=0, 202109=0, 202108=10, 202012=0}


    // This part only returns 2 rows which has data. How can I compare it with the MAP and dynamically create JSON response for 12 months
    List<Participant> participant = participantAggResults
        .stream()
        .map(x -> new Participant(
            x.getMonthKey(),
            x.getTotalParticipantsCount()))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
            Participant::getMonthKey))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return ParticipantReportDto.builder()
                    .participants(cyocChallengeParticipant)
                    .build();
  }
```

To build the dynamic map -

```
private Map<Integer, Long> getMonthParticipantMap(
      List<ParticipantAggResult> participantAggResults) {
    return participantAggResults.stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                 ParticipantAggResult::getMonthKey,
                                                 Collectors.summingLong(
                                                     ParticipantAggResult::getTotalParticipantsCount)));
  }
```

What changes shall I do in this part of the code so that it will compare it with the MAP and dynamically create JSON response for 12 months

```
List<Participant> participant = participantAggResults
            .stream()
            .map(x -> new Participant(
                x.getMonthKey(),
                x.getTotalParticipantsCount()))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                Participant::getMonthKey))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an easy approach:

- first, you calculate the starting and the ending date. I assume, from your code, that the ending date is the actual one
- for the two dates, you are interested in the year and month
- you generate a progression, that is a list of strings, representing the key for the resulting map. A key will be in the format yyyymm, so 4 charactes for the year and 2 for the month
- you transform the list to get a Map of String and Integer (change this if you need Long). The key will be the key calculated in the previous step, the value will be 0 (zero)
- you can then merge this map to the one where you have stored the values from your databse

Here's an example. Let's say you know the starting date, so you can extract the starting year and the starting month from there (remember the month's index starts from 0). The resulting function to generate the progression will be:

```
public List<String> generateKeyProgression(int startingYear, int startingMonth) {
    Date now = new Date();
    int actualMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int actualYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    
    List<String> progression = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (startingYear <= actualYear) {
        while ((startingMonth <= actualMonth)
                || (startingMonth < 12 && startingYear < actualYear)) {
            progression.add(String.valueOf(startingYear).concat(String.format("%02d", startingMonth+1)));
            startingMonth++;
        }
        startingMonth = 0;
        startingYear++;
    }
    
    return progression;
}
```

Now, assuming that you generate this progression with this line:

```
List<String> progression = generateKeyProgression(YOUR_STARTING_YEAR, YOUR_STARTING_MONTH);
```

and assuming that the ArrayList of Participants, where you've stored all the values, is called participantResults, you can do this:

```
  Map<String, Integer> participantAggResults = progression.stream()
    .map(s -> new Participant(s, 0))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Participant::getMonthKey, Participant:: getTotalParticipantsCount));
    
  Map<String, Integer> participantResultsMap = participantResults.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Participant::getMonthKey, Participant:: getTotalParticipantsCount));
    
  participantResultsMap.forEach(
    (key, value) -> participantAggResults.merge(key, value, (prev, actual) -> actual));
```

The code is pretty simple:

- we map the List to a Map<String, Integer>, where all the values are zero;
- we map the participantResults list to a Map<String, Integer>, where all the keys are the monthKey of the single participant and all the values are the total participant count of the single participant;
- we merge the two maps. We start from the first map and, if there is an item with the same key, we get its value instead of the previous one (that was set to zero). You can see we are using the "actual" value, and not the "prev" one.

After this, participantAggResults will be a Map<String, Integer>, and its keys and values will be exactly how you expect them.